# How to delete useless ssh key on my server(Ubuntu server 16.04) and generate new one

Tags: server, ssh, keyboard

I have accidentally lost my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. on my server, I had disabled ssh with a password. I still able to plug a screen on my server and log in with the keyboard. How can I remove last ssh key (from my server) since it is not useful anymore? How can I regenerate new ssh private key transfer into my laptop (Linux)?

Thank you in advance

```
ssh -V = OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g ...
```

Comment: let me get you right you want to remove known_host keys, if so just delete that folder. The second part I don't really follow...

Comment: @George I want to delete my ssh public key from the server (since I lost private), and recreate new public (for my server) and private key (for my laptop) to be able to connect again via ssh from my laptop to my server.

Comment: @George I have disabled password connection ...  Do I have to enable it or is there another way?

Comment: @George this is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @guntbert, yes you are right I totally forgot about the authorized_keys. dmx please use the answer below...

Comment: @dmx I believe your first sentence is wrong - your `known-hosts`-file never contains your keys. I suppose you lost the complete`~/.ssh` directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key will be in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

You can delete the line for the old key with the editor of your choice.

You can generate a new private key by running the following command on a client machine.

```
ssh-keygen
```

Depending on which algorithm was used add the contents of the ~/.ssh/id*.pub file to the ~/.authorized_keys file on the server.  It will be a single line

It is probably called:

```
id_rsa.pub
```

And the key will look like

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAIZ5CYnbANePH8y1rKvFIpWNWrr3kSuelNP61W/yPiPtf11DZgdWsP5eaBQQqEZpXnw57pu5SuPHe5FPn+L39c/xtPJdvn1ZSVo1OTWMPkKGX+5WuL5ypaHN5J2E4qkZD9vzQ4OcUGGdODZ676TPV5cAD7oYHvBWKdCxPUztUAAAADAQABAAIZ5CYnbANePH8y1rKvFIpWNWrr3kSuelNP6 user@foo
```

Note that it is a single line.  If you delete the authorized_keys file on the server you will need to make sure the permissions are correct.

```
chmod 0644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Is each public key on the server in the authorized_keys file separated by a new line?